# Do DBAs need to work in Shifts?

Tags: database-design

My question is, do Database Administrators (DBA) have to work in Shifts always. I am currently working as a Junior DBA. I am afraid if I have to work in Shifts in future in case I work as Database Admin.
Please share your experiences and thoughts.

Also, if yes(work is in shifts), then how can we deviate our path to some related field to avoid Shifts.

Comment: Why not ask your fellow DBA's? Expectations for working hours vary from company to company and can depend greatly on how large and spread out the company is.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to work in shifts.  But you probably will if you want to work for the larger companies, and at least as you work your way up the ranks.  If you are against working in shifts, or participating in an on-call rotation, then you can make choices to reduce that.

You can work for companies that are NOT 24/7 online.  Many smaller businesses don't have 24/7 operations.  You may be required to be more than just a DBA though, you tend to wear many hats with the smaller companies.

You can make it a condition of hiring that you not be part of a rotation.  This will severely hinder your advancement.

You can become senior enough so that you have either first pick of shifts, or are level 2 (the guys who are on call will call you when they hit a problem they can't solve).  But until then, you will be part of shift/call rotation work.

But your best bet to avoid shift work as much as possible is to diversify your skill set (add in application development and/or system/network administration) and work for smaller companies.

You could also go in and join a consulting firm and then you probably won't be supporting systems directly and have a much better chance of a "normal" working hours.  But you will probably need to be a Senior level or better.

But you have selected a field that tends to be central to a business.  If that business needs the systems to be up 24/7 then they need someone willing/able to provide support when they go down.  Even the smaller companies that I mentioned earlier will have out of normal hours work that had to be done (upgrades, deployments, migrations) so that's not a complete panacea.

But you can also ask what the number of tickets that a place gets for out of hours work.  My current company is 24/7 although we slow down a lot in the evening.  We get perhaps 2-3 tickets a month outside of normal working hours.  That's a result of the team and management working hard to make sure we don't have issues outside of normal hours.